# Items not storing to session

Tags: php, session

I am trying to store items to a session (guest user) and show the items in a cart. I can see the session exists in the log file:

```
products|a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:3:"img";s:62:"http://localhost/eCommerce%20Project/uploads/womens/w_nike.jpg";s:2:"id";s:1:"3";s:4:"name";s:11:"womens nike";s:5:"price";s:2:"14";s:3:"sku";s:3:"456";s:11:"description";s:20:"Womens Nike trainers";}}
```

Here is my code which allows me to post the item to the session, this is a on a single view of the product:

```
$product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE product_id = $product_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<img src=' . $row['product_img'] . ' />';
            echo '<div class="title">'. $row['product_name'] .'</div>';
            echo '<div class="title">'. $row['product_price'] .'</div>';
            echo '<div class="title">'. $row['product_sku'] .'</div>';
            echo '<div class="title">'. $row['product_description'] .'</div>';
            echo '<div class="title">'. $row['gender'] .'</div>';
            echo '<form action="addToCart.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_img" value="' . $row['product_img'] . '" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' . $row['product_id'] . '" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="' . $row['product_name'] . '" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="' . $row['product_price'] . '" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_sku" value="' . $row['product_sku'] . '" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="product_description" value="' . $row['product_description'] . '" />
                    <button name="addToBasket">Add to basket</button>
                  </form>';

            $gender = $row['gender'];  
        }

    }
```

The sessions are set in the header so always starting no matter which page you are on.

My cart looks like the following, theres a lot going on here but essentially the item isn't showing in the basket.

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product) {
    $name = $product['name'];
    $id = $product['id'];
    $price = $product['price'];
    $img = $product['img'];
    $sku = $product['sku'];
    $description = $product['description'];

    echo '<a href="single_product.php?product_id=' . $product['id'] . '">';
    echo "<img src='$img'><br />";
    echo "Product: $name<br />";
    echo "Price: $price | ID: $id<br />";
    echo "$description";
    echo '</a><br /><br />';
    echo '<form action="removeItem.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' . $product['id'] . '" />
            <button name="removeItem">Remove</button>
          </form>';    

    $sum += $price;

}

if($product == 0){
    echo 'Sorry no items in basket <a href="/eCommerce%20Project/">Continue shopping</a>';
}

    echo "<h4>Sub total £" . $sum . "</h4>";

    // Calulating delivery costs
    $deliveryCharge = 0; // Initial value
    if($sum > 50 || $product == 0){ // If more than £50 deliver is 0
        $deliveryCharge = 0;
    } else if($sum < 50){ // If less than £50 delivery is £15
         $deliveryCharge = 15;
    };

    // Output of delivery cost
    echo "<h4>Delivery £" . $deliveryCharge . "</h4>";    

    // Calculation for working out 20% on top of price
    $percentage = 20;
    $totalPrice = $sum;
    $totalPrice = ($percentage / 100) * $totalPrice;

    // Calculation to find totals for price + vat + delivery
    $totalPriceWithVat = $sum + $totalPrice + $deliveryCharge;

    // Output full total
    echo "<h4>Total (Inc. VAT &amp; Delivery) £" . $totalPriceWithVat . "</h4>";

    echo '<button>Checkout</button>';
```

And here is the form which actions the post:

```
if (isset($_POST['addToBasket'])) { 
    $_SESSION['products'][] = array(
        'img' => $_POST['product_img'],
        'id' => $_POST['product_id'],
        'name' => $_POST['product_name'],
        'price' => $_POST['product_price'],
        'sku' => $_POST['product_sku'],
        'description' => $_POST['product_description']
    );
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  window.location='basket.php'; </script>";
}
```

Comment: nowhere in there do you ever STORE anything in $_SESSION. You only have one instance of READING from session (a foreach loop).

Comment: @MarcB My apologies please see my updated question.

Comment: basic debugging, then: did you check if the session is actually successfully started? You just say "in the header", but doesn't mean much. `<html><head><?php session_start(); ?>` is "in the header", but is still a "headers already sent" warning.

Comment: @MarcB there are no errors spitting out I have php error reporting on and its giving me nothing back - the session should be starting on every page and if I visit each page it logs a new session in the php log file.

Comment: then check session settings. does `session_id()` stay the same on each page? if not, then you're probably losing the session cookie and getting a new/blank session every time.

Comment: so it looks like the id changes every time so when I refresh the page the session id thats logged is changing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118453/discussion-between-dan-and-marc-b).

Comment: so you'll have to start digging into your session cookie settings, client- AND server-side - figure out exactly why the cookie gets lost/ignored.

Comment: The strange thing here is that it works on MAMP on my home mac on my work Mac its dosnt work - potentially issues with the MAMP installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that session is active, else use
`session_start()`
before
`if (isset($_POST['addToBasket'])) {`.